# react-native textinput secure entry font size flicks

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I have one strange issue with react-native TextInput when

> secureTextEntry = {true}

The font size for the entire field changes to a couple sizes larger when: Typing backspace Or Waiting for a few seconds (~ 3 seconds); changing focus (tapping "return" or selecting the username field). This problem also seems to happen spontaneously when typing, where it will flicker the larger font size.

When I just remove that SecureTextEntry all works normally.

> I am attaching an images here when typing the password.

[image]

> I am attaching an images here when typing backspace.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved, I have set Value property in TextInput component. So I just removed below line attributes and that solved the problem.

> value = {this.state.text}